# Vue.js sidebar transition

Tags: vue.js

I have a sidebar and a content inside a bootstrap row and I want to animate the toggle of the sidebar and to expand seamlessly the content container, I'm applying those transition classes:

```
.slide-fade-enter {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  position: relative;
}
.slide-fade-leave, .slide-fade-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

but it flickers when expanding, you can see it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/kd6xpa32/16/

How can I prevent this?

Comment: The JsFiddle you provided is working fine, it does not flicker.
Maybe it has to do with your machine.

Comment: @FaranAli you can see it here: imgur.com/a/QwpXvkR, the yellow container flickers when doing the transition.

Comment: @dazzed you're talking about the flicker/jump when the blue "expands"?

Comment: @jshrc exactly, the flicker/jump in the yellow container when de blue one expands.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're doing some dirty stuff with flex and absolute positioning. I'd find a way to leave the sidebar as always absolutely (or relatively) positioned and figure out another way to collapse+expand it. The switch between absolute and relative is causing the rendering issue.